# Dealing with request data in controller leads to artisan errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have controllers which are responsible for handling API requests. In each constructior I use JWTAuth class like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authenticatedUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
}
```

When I run `php artisan route:list` command I got an error that JWT couldn't parse token. Obviously I don't have session data when using CLI command.

Also I get similar errors when I use session inside constructors.

Is there any way to avoid artisan errors because it looks inconvenient: I'd like to use some properties inside constructor but I couldn't if they depend on the request data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with it is to check if app is not running in the cli. Yo can do it via `\App::runningInConsole()`. So in your constructor do (easiest way)

```
if ( ! \App::runningInConsole()) {
    $this->authenticatedUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
}
```

But I would recommend you to move this to an abstract ApiController or service or even helper in order not copy/past this every time.

Answer (score -1):

Verify the user first.

```
    if (!$this->authenticatedUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Not found'], 404);
    }
```

This is good for validation inside the API, too, because people using the API could get a similar error.